# Windows taskbar tasks crash explorer.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

**Synopsis:** Whenever I execute a task via the Windows taskbar, explorer.exe immediately crashes.

**Cause:** Any item under "Tasks" causes this, from any application (see screenshot "taskbar tasks.png").

This started happening a few days ago. I have no idea what might have caused it.

**Steps taken**

1. Restart computer
2. Install Windows updates
3. Install graphics driver updates
4. Run check disk (chkdsk)
5. Run system file checker (sfc)
6. Full system scan with Symantec Endpoint Protection (latest updates)
7. Google search for similar problems

**Log data and screenshots**

[Dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/523gth02ku0q5iz/AAD4MmRkKOTwR82LvGuvCDk9a) - would have included images inline but this website is disallowing it

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          8/4/2014 15:15:18
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      F8L
Description:
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 6.1.7601.17567, time stamp: 0x4d672ee4
Faulting module name: ShellExtension.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x526fe889
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000263cbabc
Faulting process id: 0xd34
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfb01e20e55125
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: ShellExtension.dll
Report Id: 0d144da5-1c14-11e4-9672-c86000a43bab
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-08-04T20:15:18.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2176248</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>F8L</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Explorer.EXE</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.17567</Data>
    <Data>4d672ee4</Data>
    <Data>ShellExtension.dll_unloaded</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>526fe889</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00000000263cbabc</Data>
    <Data>d34</Data>
    <Data>01cfb01e20e55125</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE</Data>
    <Data>ShellExtension.dll</Data>
    <Data>0d144da5-1c14-11e4-9672-c86000a43bab</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Explorer crash is caused by a Shellextenson called `ShellExtension.dll`:

```
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE 
Faulting module path: ShellExtension.dll
```

Use [ShellExViw](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable this shell extension if there is no update available for the tool which installs it.

Comment: Thanks, so it was leftover junk upgrading from Win7. I ended up using ShellExView to disable EVERYTHING since I was hardly using any of it, and manually re-enabling what I did use (e.g. winRAR stuff).

Answer (score 1):

If it started a few days ago, it's likely that something (filepath, registry entry, who knows) got corrupted.

I suggest restoring a system restore point. To do this, go to:

**Control Panel** (icons view) **-> Recovery -> Open System Restore**

From here on out the wizard should be self-explanatory.

Comment: In my case it was upgrading to Windows 10, so this wouldn't work in that case.